# Why is response.json() returning a promise?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have this JavaScript fetch function

```
async getAllExpensesByUser() {
    let reponse = await fetch("router.php/getAll");
    console.log(reponse.json());
  }
```

also tried

```
getAllExpensesByUser = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("router.php/getAll");
    if (response.ok) {
      const jsonValue = await response.json();
      return Promise.resolve(jsonValue);
    } else {
      return Promise.reject("*** PHP file not found");
    }
  };
```

my router.php file has this code

```
   $data = $expensesController->getExpensesForUser($_SESSION['userid']);
   echo json_encode($data);
```

but `response.json()` is returning `Promise {<pending>}` and the result I need is inside of `[[PromiseResult]]`

Comment: It returns a promise because it is defined to do so: see [MDN - Body.json()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json)

Comment: Also note that you don't need to wrap `jsonValue` with `Promise.resolve`: an `async` function returns a promise - any non-promise value returned from an async function is implicitly wrapped in a promise.

Comment: In the MDN example the data is rendered inside fetch itself. What if I want to return the data and use it somewhere else? I tried doing that but when I ```console.log(data)``` in the place I wanna use it, it goes back to being a promise again.

Comment: Add the code where you try to implement the `getAllExpensesByUser` function.

Comment: `getAllExpensesByUser` function is async, this means it returns a promise. To get the value with which that promise fulfils, you can either chain `then()` method or `await` the call to `getAllExpensesByUser` function

Comment: Yes you are right, I will do that. Thank you so much

Comment: concerning the "why": data arriving from an external HTTP request is asynchronous by definition, `fetch()` resolves once the header arrived, `res.json()` then resolves when the whole body arrived and was parsed.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by Yousaf, both fetch and Body.json() return promises. To wait for both the fetch and Body.json calls to resolve before continuing, you simply need to update your code like this:

```
async getAllExpensesByUser() {
  let reponse = await fetch("router.php/getAll");
  let object = await response.json();
  console.log(object);
  return object;//If needed, see the comment by Emiel
}
```

Comment: This is useful. Thank you!

Comment: Don't forget to return the `object`.

Answer (score 1):

`response.json()` returns a Promise because this method takes a Response **stream** and reads it to completion, and this is an asynchronous process. You can find more information about it in the [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json)

What you need is just wait when the process of reading stream ends, for this purposes you can use `await` as well

```
async getAllExpensesByUser() {
  let reponse = await fetch("router.php/getAll");
  let object = await response.json();
  return object
}

...

const userExpenses = await getAllExpensesByUser()
console.log(userExpenses) 

...
```